# Why is multiprocessing.manager in python behaving weirdly?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, program-entry-point, concurrent.futures

When I run this and input something it goes into the main function but then again asks for input. Why is that even happening?
I am running using command prompt in windows. version is 3.8

```
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import concurrent.futures


input('?')

def pp(id,lock):
    with lock:
        for i in range(5):          
            print(f'{id}=>{i}')

def main():
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    futures = [pool.submit(pp, num,lock) for num in range(10)]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        executor.map(main, list(range(10)),[lock]*10)       
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output:

```
?abc
?abd
????
```

How to solve this problem so it runs the input just once?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: i am also running it as an .exe using pyinstaller.. but that also has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce, it only runs once on my local Python.
What is your Python version ?

However, I can recommend putting `input` inside the `if __name__ == "main"`. The problem is that your input is called whenever you import your module, which *could* be done by a Thread when importing the `main` function.

*Note: sorry to not post a comment, but I can't with a lower reputation than 50.*

Comment: please check again the edits. putting inside the if statement works.. but why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: Also when i convert it into an exe using pyinstaller even putting the input inside the if statement does not make it work!

Comment: As said, I think that it creates a "copy" of the module for each core (?). Therefore, the program needs to import the module (don't know why 3, do you have 3 cores ?) multiples times.